# How do you instantiate an object that has attributes that are set by functions, i.e. call them at the right time?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is my code. Basically, I am creating an object, and some of it's attributes are set by functions that need to be run once I instantiate the object. I am developing this in the Google Scripts code editor, and it runs without bugs, but doesn't actually do anything.

This function is called by a time trigger periodically

```
function addFoldersToSites(){

  //DriveObject class, has a folder id and page url, and uses those to get attachments
  function DriveObject(folder_id,page_url) {
    this.folder_id = folder_id
    this.page_url = page_url
    this.files = setFiles
    this.page = setPage
    this.attachments = setAttachments
  }
  function setFiles(){return DocsList.getFolderById(this.folder_id).getFiles();}
  function setPage(){return SitesApp.getPageByUrl(this.page_url);}
  function setAttachments(){return this.page.getAttachments();}


  //instantiate drive objects
  //if you want to add drive things to new site pages, this is where you do it
  //*************************************************************************
  var engpage = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvWWFfc1oyN0VfeTg','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/engineering/files');
  var productpage = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LveUI0dmxxLWplaTA','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/engineering/files');
  var adminpage= new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvVUVDUlBWWWhJcDg','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/home/files');
  var genonboarding = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvbjRtanE4eGNkdlE','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/home/general-onboarding');
  var salespage= new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvQ2JJN0pCblNyME0','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/sales/files');
  var researchpage = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvM1RKeHVXRkNBZ1k','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/market-research');

  //function that iterates through folder files and puts them in the google site frame
  function showFolderInSite(attachments, page, files) {
    var attachments = attachments
    var page = page
    var files = files

    for (i in attachments) {
      attachments[i].deleteAttachment();
    }

    for (i in files) {
      page.addWebAttachment(files[i].getName(), '', files[i].getUrl());
    }
  }

  //run functions
  showFolderInSite(engpage.attachments,engpage.page,engpage.files)
  showFolderInSite(productpage.attachments,productpage.page,productpage.files)
  showFolderInSite(adminpage.attachments,adminpage.page,adminpage.files)
  showFolderInSite(genonboarding.attachments,genonboarding.page,genonboarding.files)
  showFolderInSite(salespage.attachments,salespage.page,salespage.files)
  showFolderInSite(researchpage.attachments,researchpage.page,researchpage.files)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only atomic way to instantiate an object with all of it's attributes set at once is to pass them all to the constructor function.

Then, the constructor can use those arguments to call any other functions that might need to process those arguments as part of the proper initialization.

So, you basically have these two choices (where the first is the more atomic initalizer):

```
function myConstructor(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    this.whatever = a;
    this.aabb = processArg(b, c);
    // etc...
}

var myObj = new myConstructor(true, 3, "foo", 4, 5, 6);
```

or this:

```
function myConstructor() {
}
myConstructor.prototoype = {
    init1: function(a, b) {},
    init2: function(a, b) {},
    init3: function(a, b) {},
}

var myObj = new myConstructor();
myObj.init1(true, 3);
myObj.init2("foo", 4);
myObj.init3(5, 6);
```

The first option is more atomic and puts less burden on the caller to make all the proper initialization calls, but the second option is more flexible if there are multiple different ways to initialize the object.  I prefer the former because it's generally better to make fewer ways for the caller to screw up, but occasionally the second option's flexibility is useful.

Comment: yeah, the second one is also just foreign to me. Let me try and apply the first approach to my specific issue and see how it goes

Comment: so in your example, when I make a new `myConstructor` called `myObj`, it doesn't set attribute `aabb` until I specifically call `myObj.aabb` ?

Comment: @Brian - myConstructor is just a function.  No instance variables of the object (other than those that are prespecified in the prototype) are set until the function sets them.  The arguments to the constructor do nothing on your own.  Your constructor function code has to do something with the arguments.  So, in my first example, the property `.aabb` doesn't even exist until it is assigned in the constructor function.

Comment: by this logic, my code should work though. I have to be honest, I still don't understand why mine is not working. I instantiate the object, passing in the appropriate arguments, and then call on the attributes that are populated by functions using the arguments.

Comment: @Brian - can you be a lot more specific about what doesn't work in your code?  "not working" doesn't give us much to go on.  Also, are you allergic to semi-colons.  Javascript statements should end with a semicolon.

Comment: @Brian - In looking at your code further, it looks like you're confused about a function reference and calling/executing a function.  `engpage.attachments` is a function reference that points to the `setAttachments` function.  `engpage.attachments()` would execute that function and take on the value that the function returns.

Comment: oh lawd, I'm so used to ruby. Sorry about the unspecific caterwauling. Let me fix the parens and ; and get back to you

Comment: all is well. thank you kind sir for your patience, wisdom, and magnanimity.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for(also make sure DocsList and SitesApp are accessible):

```
function addFoldersToSites(){

        //DriveObject class, has a folder id and page url, and uses those to get attachments
        function DriveObject(folder_id,page_url) {
            this.folder_id = folder_id;
            this.page_url = page_url;
            this.showFolderInSite();
        }
        DriveObject.prototype = {};
        DriveObject.prototype.constructor = DriveObject;
        DriveObject.prototype.files = function setFiles(){return DocsList.getFolderById(this.folder_id).getFiles();}
        DriveObject.prototype.page = function setPage(){return SitesApp.getPageByUrl(this.page_url);}
        DriveObject.prototype.attachments = function setAttachments(){return this.page.getAttachments();}
    //function that iterates through folder files and puts them in the google site frame
        DriveObject.prototype.showFolderInSite = function showFolderInSite() {
            var attachments = this.attachments();
            var page = this.page();
            var files = this.files();

            for (i in attachments) {
                attachments[i].deleteAttachment();
            }

            for (i in files) {
                page.addWebAttachment(files[i].getName(), '', files[i].getUrl());
            }
        }

        //instantiate drive objects
        //if you want to add drive things to new site pages, this is where you do it
        //*************************************************************************
        var engpage = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvWWFfc1oyN0VfeTg','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/engineering/files');
        var productpage = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LveUI0dmxxLWplaTA','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/engineering/files');
        var adminpage= new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvVUVDUlBWWWhJcDg','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/home/files');
        var genonboarding = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvbjRtanE4eGNkdlE','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/home/general-onboarding');
        var salespage= new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvQ2JJN0pCblNyME0','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/sales/files');
        var researchpage = new DriveObject('0B6esS6X9k9LvM1RKeHVXRkNBZ1k','https://sites.google.com/a/drawbrid.ge/resources/market-research');
    }
```